# Should a model that participates in an association specify id fields for each associated resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

For example, if we consider two models, Product and Brand, should I declare a field for each associated document's id in each model?

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, :type => String
  field :brand_id, :type => Moped::BSON::ObjectId

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :brand_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :brand
end
```

--

```
class Brand
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :description, :type => String
  field :product_id, :type => Moped::BSON::ObjectId

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :product_id, presence:true

  has_many :products
end
```

The fields `brand_id` and `product_id` are both created automatically regardless of whether the model declares that they exist, so the code works whether they are included or not. I am just curious about what standard practice is for this sort of thing.

Comment: The docs (http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many) cover these cases. Seems like you want `belongs_to` and `has_many` like you've got, and no further declaration is needed.

Comment: Thanks, the thing that confused me was setting validations for these fields. It seems strange to validate fields that aren't explicitly defined in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong...

In class Brand, you shouldn't have 'product_id' if there is a  *has_many* relationship.

Class  Product is Ok.